# set API key source to Authorizer in AWS::Serverless::Api

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have an API defined via a CloudFormation `AWS::Serverless::Api` object.  I need it to take usage plan keys from its custom authorizer, equivalently to [Setting ApiKeySourceType to AUTHORIZER on an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-apikeysourcetype).  How can this be done?

This is the current definition that I'm using, including an OpenAPI definition exported from a correctly-configured API.  I do think it's odd that `x-api-key` is still listed for api_key even after setting the config to AUTHORIZER.

```
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-API
      StageName: !Ref ApiStageName
      MethodSettings:
        - CachingEnabled: false
          DataTraceEnabled: false
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          MetricsEnabled: true
          ResourcePath: '/*'
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: !Ref ThrottlingBurstLimit
          ThrottlingRateLimit: !Ref ThrottlingRateLimit
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt ApiLogs.Arn
        # format is copied from an example generated by the web console
        Format: '{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","routeKey":"$context.routeKey", "status":"$context.status","protocol":"$context.protocol", "responseLength":"$context.responseLength" }'
      CacheClusterEnabled: false
      TracingEnabled: true
      DefinitionBody: !Sub |
        openapi: "3.0.1"
        paths:
          /v2/oauth2/token:
            post:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                connectionId: "${RestApiVpcLink}"
                httpMethod: "POST"
                uri: "http://${VPCLinkLB.DNSName}/v2/oauth2/token"
                passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
                connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
                type: "http_proxy"
          /{proxy+}:
            x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
              parameters:
                - name: "proxy"
                  in: "path"
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: "string"
              security:
                - LambdaAuthorizer: []
                - api_key: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                connectionId: "${RestApiVpcLink}"
                httpMethod: "ANY"
                uri: "http://${VPCLinkLB.DNSName}/{proxy}"
                requestParameters:
                  integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
                passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
                connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
                type: "http_proxy"
        components:
          securitySchemes:
            LambdaAuthorizer:
              type: apiKey
              name: Authorization
              in: header
              x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
              x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
                authorizerUri: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GatewayAuthorizerLambda.Arn}/invocations"
                authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
                identityValidationExpression: "Bearer .*"
                type: "token"
            api_key:
              type: "apiKey"
              name: "x-api-key"
              in: "header"
```

I'm mostly using `Serverless::Api` rather than its component `ApiGateway` objects because I've found stages/deployments to be a huge headache otherwise.

Comment: continuing to dig on this, it looks like the console's export does not include x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source which may be critical here.

Answer (score 0):

`x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: AUTHORIZER` needed to be added as a sibling to `openapi: "3.0.1"`.  That openAPI extension is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-api-key-source.html).

It looks like there must be a bug in the stage export which is causing this to be missing.